# Using classes in dwsunit

Tags: delphi, dwscript

1- Why is it necessary to name the methods of a class in a dwsunit this way?

```
dwsUnitClasses'ClassName''MethodName'Eval(Info: TProgramInfo; 
                                          var ExtObject: TObject)
```

2- Is there a link that must be done between the method defined in a dwsunit and its code? 
  coz it is not working with me. I took the demo attached with the DWscript (Custom Classes)   and made something that looks like it but it is just not functioning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not necessary, that's just the format the IDE uses for auto-generated event names.

Usually you define script classes, their methods in the structure view, then you double-click their OnEval (or other) event in the properties editor, the IDE will create a method with a name like the above and you can implement there.

If you declare the methods manually, then you also have to attach their events manually, but it's not different than what you end up doing for a button click event (and where you end up with a Button1Click method).

Apart from the implementation code itself, most of the declarations in DWScript can happen at design-time, and are stored in the DFM. The Structure View is convenient for that, but you can also use the property editor only (it was even more convenient in older Delphi versions, when the structure view was sticking to design-time structures, rather than being reused for source structure).

Comment: I missed attaching the event by the declared method, I didn't notice the OnEval at first. Thanks alot ;)